# PreviewMouseDown for Disabled Button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseevent

I want to fire **PreviewMouseDown** event when I hit disabled button, Is it Possible ?

If not, Is there any event can I access to by click on disabled button ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by creating a custom control with a button and an empty TextBlock over it. I don't know if it's the best solution but I know that it works.

If you want more information, what I did was the TextBlock is always invisible unless the button is disabled. Therefore normal events go to the button and when it's disabled mouse events go to the TextBlock. It only works with mouse events and if you want keyboard input you need to overlay it with a focus supported control.

Comment: Thanks for you suggest, see my solution. If you need the detail tell me

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using **IsHitTestVisible** properties for the button.

More detail about IsHitTestVisible [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx)

Hope this help.